# WCF Service call fails second time when calling from windows service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am building windows service application which will have to call WCF service periodically. The problem is that the first call of the service is always successfull, I get response as expected, but the second and any other request after fails and I get following exception:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https:XXXXXXXXXXXX. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>   ...

My windows service is built using System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.
For making periodical calls I am using System.Timers.Timer class like this:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            InitTimer();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }

    private void InitTimer()
    {
        Timer apiPollingTimer = new Timer(60000); // 1 minute

        apiPollingTimer.Elapsed += ((sender, e) =>
        {
            OnTimerElapsed(sender, e);
        });
        apiPollingTimer.Enabled = true;
        apiPollingTimer.AutoReset = true;

        apiPollingTimer.Start();
    }

    protected void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
            ServiceResult result = client.GetUpdateTimes();

            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }
```

This is binding configuration for WCF endpoint:

```
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="transportSecurity" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
       openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
       allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
       maxBufferSize="655360000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360000"
       messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
       useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="655360000"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

**Edit:** This is client and behaviors config:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://XXXXXXXXXXXX"
      behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertBehavior"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="transportSecurity"
      contract="GetUpdateTimesInterface"
      name="GetUpdateTimes" />
</client>

    <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ClientCertBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber" findValue="xx xx xx"/>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Edit 2:** Binding part from service wsdl:

```
      <wsdl:binding name="ServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:GetUpdateTimesInterface">
    <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetUpdateTimes">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:GetUpdateTimes" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="GetUpdateTimes">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="GetUpdateTimesResponse">
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="GetUpdateTimesService">
    <wsdl:port name="GetUpdateTimes" binding="tns:ServiceSoapBinding">
      <soap12:address location="http:XXXXX"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

What I tried so far is to change quota properties, but it didn't help, I am still getting same exception second time service is called. Also if I make simple console application where I copy paste same timer implementation and binding configuration I don't get the exception, the service gets called and returns response every single time, it only fails when I install this windows service.

Also I don't have access to WCF service implementation and only have it's wsdl to work with.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit 3:**
I have made some inspection using Fiddler, what I have noticed is the first time service is called header Connection: Keep-Alive is added and SessionID is empty, while the second time SessionID is added. I was thinking maybe there is a way to remove Connection: Keep-Alive from calls or clear SessionID if it's present would help. Here is a picture requests / responses from Fiddler: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8apw.png)

**Edit 4:**

Tried replacing basicHttpBinding with customBinding and to set keepAliveEnabled but it didn't help:

```
      <customBinding>
    <binding name="customTransportSecurity" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
       openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8" />
      <httpsTransport keepAliveEnabled="false" transferMode="Buffered" requireClientCertificate="true"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="655360000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360000" realm="" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159406/discussion-on-question-by-mm2-wcf-service-call-fails-second-time-when-calling-fr).